# Didn't get notification for comment on my answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, notifications, global-inbox

"1 hour ago", someone commented on an [answer I gave](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/851/preview-treats-as-comment/1921#1921) on meta.tex.se:

[image: answer with comment]

However, I didn't get a notification for that comment, the latest notification in my inbox is from "6 hours ago":

[image: inbox without notification]

The latest notification leads to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/why-cant-fi-be-separated-when-being-copied-from-a-compiled-pdf):
[image: comment of latest notification]

AFAIK, users should always be notified of comments to their own posts, right? I don't know if this problem can be reproduced, but it sure is a bug.

Responding to Kevin's comment -- The comment *does* show up on the responses tab of my meta.tex.se profile (but still not in the inbox):

[image: comment on responses tab]

Comment: Indeed, users should always be notified of comments to their own posts and of new answer or comment on their own question. Smells like a bug..

Comment: Does [your responses tab](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4012/doncherry?tab=responses) show the response, or is it missing there, too?

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Good question checking that, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment should appear in your inbox now.

It's not entirely clear what happened to drop it in the first place, whatever if it is isn't reproducible (at least not easily).  Investigations continue.

Comment: confirmed. [filler] have a nice day everybody :)

Comment: Happened to me too today.. the comment made by AJSwift on [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8328490/447356) didn't give any notification in [my inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/201110?tab=inbox) can you please look into it and see if any others failed as well? Noticed this only by chance..

Comment: @Kevin any insights? It [happened to somebody else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116158/missing-a-notification-for-a-comment-in-my-global-inbox) as well.

Comment: I've had a vague feeling that not all comments made it through to the inbox, though I've only ever found them _days_ later and wasn't positive that _I_ hadn't screwed up. _Sometimes_ I see comments appear in the inbox again a few hours later, even after viewing them once, always after suspending / resuming my computer. Related? Or just noise? :)

Comment: @Kevin There's another such case here: [Missing Inbox Notification](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2641)

Comment: Another case (it’s 2014 now → notification in the new top bar): [Notification bar misses a comment to one of my answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227212/193139)