# Answer to a question doesn't appear in my global inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Didn't get notification for comment on my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110904/didnt-get-notification-for-comment-on-my-answer)

I've been using [my global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/3306?tab=inbox) to keep an eye out for new answers to my questions.  But the answer to [What parts of the Central or South Coast of California should I consider when looking for a surfing beach with beachfront hotels?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/) isn't there.

Also, I think I had a bounty on that question, but it may have expired before I saw the answer.  Can I look at the question's history to see if it did have a bounty?  I've accepted the answer, but if there was a bounty the answerer missed out on it.  Would it be appropriate for me to create a new bounty and assign it to him, after the mandatory delay has passed?

Comment: For some reason it does not appear in the question [history](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/2831/timeline) (think it should appear) but you indeed offered +50 bounty as seen in [your profile](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/859/daryl-spitzer?tab=bounties#page_1-bsort_offered).

Comment: May be related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110904/didnt-get-notification-for-comment-on-my-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar issue to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110904/didnt-get-notification-for-comment-on-my-answer/110978#110978).

I have fixed the data, we're still investigating the cause.

Comment: What can I do about the bounty (which has expired so I can no longer assign it)?