# How can I assign a bounty that expired before I noticed an answer that didn't appear in my inbox due to a bug?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

I didn't notice the answer to [What parts of the Central or South Coast of California should I consider when looking for a surfing beach with beachfront hotels?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/) because the answer didn't appear in my inbox.  (See [Answer to a question doesn't appear in my global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110956/).)  So I missed the chance to assign the bounty to the answerer (whose answer I ultimately accepted) before it expired.  How can I make sure the answerer gets the bounty he deserves?

<strike>I suggest that email be sent out warning question posters that bounty will expire.  (Though that may have been susceptible to the same bug.)</strike>

**Update:** I withdraw the above feature request.  I see that I did receive the email, but it just didn't appear in my Gmail priority inbox.

Also, my question is based on the mistaken assumption that the answer was posted before the bounty expired.  But the answers are so good that I wouldn't want to delete the question.  Do you think the question should be edited to something like "How do I display when the bounty for a question has expired?"

Comment: You will get an email two days before the bounty period is over. Or do you mean the grace period?

Comment: I don't think you need to revise this question. It may have been a mistaken premise, but it was an honest mistake. Our answers gear towards both the exact situation and that of the broader scenario, so it remains addressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hang on. You started the bounty at 12:23 on the 21st October and it expired at 15:21 on the 29th October (7 days + 1 day grace period + time for system to notice) as per the [revision history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/2831/revisions) of your post:

[image]

The [accepted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/what-parts-of-the-central-or-south-coast-of-california-should-i-consider-when-lo/3168#3168) on your post was created at 20:05 on the 31st October, ***over 48 hours after the bounty expired.*** See:

[image]

Since the answer came *after* the bounty ended, that's unfortunate and your bounty is lost. But, I'm not sure where the problem is?

Answer (score 5):

The bounty started on October 21st, and ended at October 29th. You can see it in the [question revision history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/2831/revisions). Meanwhile, that answer was posted on October 31st, *after* the bounty had already ended. You did not miss the chance to award the bounty because there never was a chance to award the bounty to that answer.

Emails are already sent in regards to the end of the bounty period, whether or not you opt in for them, in fact. Furthermore, we provide a 24 hour grace period immediately following the end of the bounty period, explicitly for your purpose of reviewing any last-minute candidates. This will not have helped in this current scenario (as, again, the answer is after the bounty completely ended), but in the future, it is a good idea to simply check during the grace period and assign appropriately.