# Notification bar misses a comment to one of my answers

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, top-bar

(Similar to this [old non-reproducible issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110904/193139).)

2014-03-26 21:18:41Z: I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673283/1591669).
2014-03-26 22:48:32Z: OP added a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671862/google-plus-snippet-image-thumbnail-is-not-shown/22673283#comment34542258_22673283) to my answer.

I did not get any notification. In fact, my notification list (in the top bar) doesn’t list this comment at all:

[image: Screenshot of comment notifications]

As you can see, there is an entry from 2014-03-**25** and an entry from 2014-03-**27**, but the comment is from 2014-03-**26**.

This comment is correctly listed in my profile’s responses tab.